# JS - regex works on regex101 but not in my Node script

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex

On regex101 this search works perfectly: https://regex101.com/r/z8JCpv/1

But in my Node script the third matched group `array[2]` returns the matching text but also everything following it.

Here's a sample line from the source:

`/company/update?id=28524</a>'&gt;</span><span>My Target Text 1234-1232</span><span>&lt;/<span cla`

Here's my script:

```
const readline = require('readline');

const file = readline.createInterface({
  input: fs.createReadStream('search-source.txt'),
  output: process.stdout,
  terminal: false,
});

file.on('line', (line) => {
  let regex =
    /[^.*](update\?id=\d+<\/a>\'&gt;<\/span><span>)(.*)(<\/span>)[^.*]/;
  let regArray = line.match(regex);
  if (regArray) console.log(regArray.length);//4
  if (regArray) console.log(regArray[2]);
});
```

It has to be something simple that I'm missing. Thanks!

Comment: What's exactly you try to get from your sample line?

Comment: `[^.*]` is a character group meaning: not dot(.) and not star (.). I don't think that's your intention

Comment: BTW: Notice that regex101.com automatically add the `gm`flags.

Answer (score 1):

you are missing `gm` flags in your regex
Also, it's better use `regex.exec()` instead:

```js
const line = "/company/update?id=28524</a>'&gt;</span><span>My Target Text 1234-1232</span><span>&lt;/<span cla"
let regex =/[^.*](update\?id=\d+<\/a>\'&gt;<\/span><span>)(.*)(<\/span>)[^.*]/gm;
let regArray = regex.exec(line);
if (regArray) console.log(regArray.length);//4
if (regArray) console.log(regArray[2]);
```